# AngularJS set variable during iteration in template

Tags: angularjs, variables, templates, iteration

I need to display a list of messages with a "header" which contain only de date of the messages below, something like this:

```
2014-12-24
Message 1
Message 2
Message 3
2014-12-21
Test 1
Test 2
```

etc.

I have the follow json:

```
[
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-24",
        message: "Message 1"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-24",
        message: "Message 2"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-24",
        message: "Message 3"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-21",
        message: "Test 1"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-21",
        message: "Test 2"
    },
]
```

How can I do that during iteration in a template using AngularJS?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display created_at only when this value is not the same as previous one.

```
   <h3 ng-if="data[$index-1].created_at != item.created_at">
        {{item.created_at}}
   </h3>
```

And you have to sort your data. E.g.

```
$scope.data = $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, 'created_at', true);
```

But ofc, you should improve sorting because 'created_at' property is string (not date).

Example http://jsfiddle.net/t4z1joj5/

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

```
var json = [
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-24",
        message: "Message 1"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-24",
        message: "Message 2"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-24",
        message: "Message 3"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-21",
        message: "Test 1"
    },
    {
        created_at: "2014-12-21",
        message: "Test 2"
    },
];

var data = _.groupBy(val, 'created_at');
```

It will group your json array by created_at value.